# Change the location of the window form in c#?

Tags: winforms

In window application, using c# i created one form and put visible false  minimize, maximize button and formborder to none, i place one panel at top of the form, in that panel i place close, minimize buttons. Now how can i drag the window form. Any reference please. my code is

```
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241812/move-a-c-sharp-form-without-border-style

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You want to be able to drag the dialog but you can't for some reason?

Comment: No Brandon, when i visible false the form border i am not able to drag the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply register the `MouseDown`, `MouseMove` and `MoueUp` events for your `Panel`

```
    bool MouseDownFlag = false;
    Point start = new Point(0, 0);

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        start = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        MouseDownFlag = true;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MouseDownFlag)
        {
            Point newPoint = new Point();
            newPoint.X = this.Location.X - (start.X - e.X);
            newPoint.Y = this.Location.Y - (start.Y - e.Y);

            this.Location = newPoint;
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseDownFlag = false;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Afshin, thanks for replying, how can i register events, is there any reference

Comment: In the Properties pane of your Form, in the Events section, double click on each of MouseDown, MouseMove, MouseUp events so that a method is generated automatically for each event, or in the Load event of your form add codes likes this.MouseDown += panel1_MouseDown; ....